# gcloud - ERROR: gcloud crashed (GeneralProxyError): (0, 'connection closed unexpectedly' )

Tags: proxy, gcloud

'gcloud init' keeps on crashed with the error "ERROR: gcloud crashed (GeneralProxyError): (0, 'connection closed unexpectedly' )". I have looked at the source code where it crashes, and it appears as if the socket is sending data, but the data is never being received on the other end. Once no data is received, this exception occurs.

I have consulted with my cybersecurity team to configure my proxy settings, so I know those are correct, but the error still persists. I have been having this error for several days, but cannot figure it out. Any help would be great!

Note: The source code I am referring to is in socks__init__.py on line 142.

Comment: Have you tried setting the proxy settings yet? https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/proxy-settings

Answer (score 1):

That still sounds like you might have missed some proxy setting. Please go through [this documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/proxy-settings) and [this page as well](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/properties#proxy) and make sure everything checks out. If that fails, try running some commands with the `--log-http` flag to see in more detail what exactly is going wrong, as this flag will explain to you in detail how it's interacting with the Platform and which part of its interaction is failing.